# Editing Site Package Does Nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, site-packages

To test, I have commented out all the .py files within one of my python site-packages and saved the files.

Upon restart of terminal and ipython, all the old functionality of the package still works somehow. I tested further by copying the site-package folder with a different name, and the new name works. I then delete this folder, after which the new name does not work. I then recopy the folder with a new name but comment out all the code. It still works...

What is going on?!

Edit: I know it is frowned upon to edit site-packages. I'm just trying to understand what is happening. Please don't lynch me :D

Answer (score 0):

Found out why: the **init**.py file was still referencing the location of the old site-package, so was basically still using the original